# Dynamic URL in WordPress Navigation

Tags: php, wordpress

So I currently have Wordpress with some navigation links along these lines:

Link 1 | Link 2 | Link 3 etc.

Two things, first I'm trying to add a link inbetween Link 2 and Link 3. I am using this code, but it adds the link to the end of the unordered list. Is there a way to specify it's position?

```
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {

        $items .= '<li><a href=#">Test Link</a></li>';
    return $items;
}
```

Secondly, I would like this new link to have a dynamic URL containing the users ID. I've tried looking up information regarding `get_currentuserinfo();` with wordpress, but I can't seem to find a way to include it in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can specify the filter priority with add_filter, try to play with the value `10` until your nav item is in the right position.
2. You need to set a global variable `$current_user` before calling the function.

#### Code

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you, using the `global $current_user;` fixed my one issue, but for some reason, changing the `10` to different numbers still does not correct the order issue. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

I added a  filter to wp_nav_menu in my functions.php page:

```
function wp_username_in_nav( $menu ){
    global $current_user;
    return $menu = str_replace('--username--', $current_user->user_login, $menu );
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'wp_username_in_nav' );
```

Then in my menu, I added a Link menu item with a URL like this: /rootfolder/members/--username--/profile/edit/

This enabled me to dynamically add a username to a menu item.